# Redirecting to an error page in a non mapped method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was looking for a way to redirect to an error page in a method that has no mapping / direct request, but is called from a method with one.

Example:

// Calling method

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String listUploadedFiles() {    
    doSomething(); // redirect if error must happen in side this method!
    return "uploadForm";
}
```

// Method where redirection should happen

```
public void doSomething()
{
    try {
        // try some code here
    } catch(Exception e) {
       // call a method which redirects to an error page
    } 
}
```

The method above is called from a method which has a mapping, I want to redirect to an error directly in the method where the exception occurs. Is this possible with spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) like in

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String listUploadedFiles() {    
    doSomething(); // redirect if error must happen in side this method!
    return "uploadForm";
}


public void doSomething() {
    try {
        // try some code here
    } catch(Exception e) {
       throw new YourException();
    } 
}

@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
public String handleYourException(YourException e) {
    return "errorPage";
}
```

Comment: This will work only for this class. But if you want to make ```@ExceptionHandler``` works for several controllers classes, just create class and annotate it with ```@ControllerAdvice```, and put there method with ```@ExceptionHandler``` from this answer.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly